# Why do I need extra rules that are the same as the default behavior in the iptables?

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am trying to understand the below iptables config file:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
# Allow WiFi AP traffic over 80 & 8080
-A INPUT -i p2p0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i p2p0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
# Drop any traffic to port 80 & 8080
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -p tcp --dport 1502 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

My question is if the default INPUT chain is accept than why do I need these two other rules to accept WIFI connection?

Also about this line:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

What is the purpose of the '-m tcp'? what will be the difference if I do it like this:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Rules are processed in order. Without the `ACCEPT` rules on `p2p0` the relevant packets would match on the subsequent rules and be dropped, regardless of the default for the `INPUT` chain.

`-m tcp` loads the TCP module; `iptables` does not otherwise know about things like TCP port numbers and other such protocol details. If you add a rule without `-m tcp` then iptables will add it for `-p tcp` rules:

```
[root@localhost]~# iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 12345 -j DROP
[root@localhost]~# iptables-save | grep 12345
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 12345 -j DROP
                ^^^^^^
```

You may want to allow for traffic on the loopback interface, by the way.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer! Just one more thing -- if I understood correctly I need the p2p rule because if not  the packet will drop because of the TCP rule? so if I make the default DROP can I delete the TCP rules and leave only the p2p rules?